# Appveyor docker mounts fail

Tags: appveyor

- Appveyor Visual Studio 2017 image
- Simple command in the install: section of the .appveyor.yaml:

  docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data

I always get

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid bind mount spec "c:/Users:/data": 
invalid volume specification: 'c:\Users:\data'.
```

I've tried lots of ways of specifying the volume (//c/Users, /c/Users, LOTS)

It's possible that appveyor image doesn't have the C drive shared and that's the problem? How would we cause it to be shared?

Comment: Over in https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/888 @friism says that it's not possible to run linux containers on Windows Server 2016 + Docker-ee. That would be unfortunate!

Comment: Per discussion with Appveyor support this is a nonstarter.
1. Appveyor test containers (Windows) are created with docker-ee, so docker-ee is set up with windows containers. 
2. Those containers (used for test) do not have the capability of running nested virtualization, meaning they have no way to run linux containers.

Comment: As of Feb 2019 the Windows Server 2019 image with linux containers is supported, but has to be explicitly added to user account.

Answer (score -2):

For Windows correct mounting syntax is `c:/Users:c:/data` (to mount host directory `C:\Users` as container directory `C:\data`):

```
docker run --rm -v c:/Users:c:/data alpine dir c:\data
```

Comment: Thanks... but this is Windows host being mounted into a linux container. The example I gave used related syntax right?

    docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data